# Social icons in footer

Tags: html, css

Here is my html:

```
<div class="footer-social">
    <span>Connect with us:</span>
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">
        <img src='http://www.womenactionmedia.org/cms/assets/themes/crate/images/social/facebook.png' />
    </a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.twitter.com">
    <img src='http://grfx.cstv.com/schools/wis/graphics/icon_twitter24.jpg' />
</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.youtube.com">
    <img src='http://mylzh.net/wiki/worldofwarcraft/images/5/5d/Icon-youtube-22x22.png' />
</a></li>
```

and here is my css:

```
.footer-social { float: right; margin-top:5px;}
.footer-social li { display: inline;}
.footer-social span { margin-top: -20px;}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qNTL2/

I want the "Connect with us:" to be centered with the images, but it seems no matter how hard i try, it isn't working out. Anybody know why or possibly have a solution to my issue?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You need to use `<ul>` and `</ul>` when using `<li>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to add `<ul>` and `</ul>` when using `<li>` and then i dont know how you want it centered, so i made 2 demo's for you.

You mean centered like this?

```
.footer-social { float: right; margin-top:5px; height:30px; }
.footer-social ul {float:left; padding:0; margin:0;}
.footer-social li {float:left; list-style:none; margin-left:5px;}
.footer-social span { float:left; }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qNTL2/5/)**

Or more like this?

```
.footer-social { float: right; margin-top:5px; }
.footer-social ul { padding:0; margin:0 0 0 10px;}
.footer-social li {float:left; list-style:none; margin-left:5px;}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/qNTL2/10/)**

Comment: I used some of your answer to find a solution to what i needed, but ultimately I ended up doing something a little different, but for some reason it doesnt show up right on jsfiddle... maybe you have an answer why? http://jsfiddle.net/qNTL2/18/

Comment: Why dont you use my DEMO 2 than ?

Comment: Because, although it shows up in jsfiddle like that, it actually looks like demo one on my website.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited CSS of yours**

```
.footer-social { float: right; margin-top:5px;}
.footer-social li { display: inline;float:right;}
.footer-social span { margin-top: -20px;}
```

Edited this part

```
 .footer-social li { display: inline;float:right;}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qNTL2/9/)